# Entity Framework adds additional records on Add

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I'm doing a simple LINQ insert, and every time that I do the insert it adds an additional record each time.  So the first time I do an insert it correctly inserts one record.  The second time it adds the record twice, third time it adds 3 records and so on.  When I step through it I can actually see it loop threw each time but I cannot figure out why.

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SubmitSubpoenaRequest(SubpoenaRequestVM vm)
    {       
        var addRequest = _context.AddRequest(vm);
        return RedirectToAction("SubpoenaHome", new { userid = addRequest.UserID, clientid = addRequest.ClientID });    
    }
```

Insert Logic

```
    public SubpoenaRequestVM AddRequest(SubpoenaRequestVM vm)
    {
        vm.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        vm.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        vm.Active = 1;

        var model = vm.Adapt<SubpoenaRequest>();
        db.SubpoenaRequests.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var requestVM = model.Adapt<SubpoenaRequestVM>();
        return requestVM;
    }
```

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Please add the definition of SubpoenaRequest entity and whatever configuration you have set up for it.  Offhand, the first thing I'd be looking for is misconfigured bi-directional references. Any children within SubpoenaRequest?

Comment: Problem does not seem to be at server side. It must be at client side. If SubmitSubpoenaRequest is getting called multiple times it means at your client side it is looped because of some bug. Otherwise it is getting called once only but still getting multiple items then problem would be in vm.Adapt<SubpoenaRequest>()